# Get the return type of a class method by name in Typescript

Tags: typescript, sinon

I've been struggling with this issue for a bit.
I'm using Sinon to mock my db but I want to augment the type information available. If mock every method I have the type info available but as soon as I create a function wrapper, things start to get messy.

Here's the deal. I have a function that is called `mockDatabaseMethodByName` that takes a db method name and the return value. It works but I want the return value to be inferred based on the method name.

If I do this, I have all the type info available in the return type:

```js
  sinon.stub("Database.prototype", "addUser").returns(...)
```

But If I make it generic, where `name` type is `keyof Database` and also `typeof Database.protoype` (tried both), there's no type information available, of course, because Sinon doesn't have idea which value will be used.

```js
  sinon.stub("Database.prototype", name).returns(...)
```

So what I want to do is tell Sinon explicitly the return type of my function, but I can't do it dynamically, i.e:

```js
  type FooReturnType = ReturnType<Database["addUser"]>;
```

But if I do this it'll complain that type `Database` cannot be used as index type.

```js
  type FooReturnType = ReturnType<Database[typeof name]>;
```

I mean, this kind of makes sense. It looks like there isn't a clever way to tell, but I wonder if there's a chance I could do this:

```js
mockDatabaseMethodByName("addUser", { id: 5 });
```

and get type information (i.e complain if `5` is a string and not a number)